# If $(S_{n}x,y)\to(Sx,y)$ and $(T_{n}x,y)\to(Tx,y)$ for all $x,y\in H$, then $(S_{n}T_{n}x,y)\to(STx,y)$ for all $x,y\in H$.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $H$ be a hilbert space (with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$) and suppose that $(S_{n})$ and $(T_{n})$ are sequences of bounded operators from $H$ to $H$ such that $(S_{n}x,y)\to(Sx,y)$ and $(T_{n}x,y)\to(Tx,y)$ for all $x,y\in H$. Is it then true that $(S_{n}T_{n}x,y)\to(STx,y)$ for all $x,y\in H$? I tried the following:

\begin{align*}
|((S_{n}T_{n}-ST)x,y)|&\leq|((S_{n}T_{n}-ST_{n})x,y)|+|((ST_{n}-ST)x,y)|\\
&=|((S_{n}-S)(T_{n}x),y)|+|(T_{n}-T)(x),S^{*}y)|.
\end{align*}

It is clear that $|(T_{n}-T)(x),S^{*}y)|\to0$, but I'm not sure about the convergence of $|((S_{n}-S)(T_{n}x),y)|$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will say that $S_n\to S$ in the **weak operator topology** when for all $x,y\in H$ it is $\langle S_nx,y\rangle\to\langle Sx,y\rangle$. Your question is: is multiplication sequentially continuous with respect to the weak operator topology? The answer is no.

For example, consider $H=\ell^2$ and for $x=(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ set $$S_nx= (x_n,x_{n+1},\dots)$$ and $$T_nx=(0,\dots,0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$$
where the number of $0$'s in the definition of $T_n$ is $n$. It is easy to verify that $(S_n),(T_n)\subset B(H)$ and also $S_n,T_n\to0$ in WOT. But on the other hand we have that $S_nT_n=\text{Id}_H$, so $S_nT_n\not\to 0$ in WOT.

It is true however that if $S_n\to S$ in WOT, then $S_nT\to ST$ and $TS_n\to TS$ in WOT. There are some more relative results, but multiplication is not continuous with respect to WOT in general.